# How can I upgrade the L1 resonators on my faction's portal to L2?

Tags: ingress

Today I found a portal owned by my faction that had a full house of 8 L1 resonators. I have a couple L2 resonators in my item inventory and wanted to deploy one. From the portal's main actions screen I selected `Upgrade`. From there I was shown a close up of the existing resonators that I could cycle through. Unfortunately, the `Upgrade` option on each of them was grayed out for me. Clicking on it only produce a text-over error:

> No usable resonators

I checked my items list and there are still two L2 resonators in my inventory. What am I doing wrong? How can I deploy these resonators to the portal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You **cannot deploy resonators that are higher level** than you, even if you have them in inventory. If this is the case, only way to do the upgrade is to first upgrade your access level (ie. level up ;) ).

If you had L2 resonators and are L2 or higher player level, then it is likely to be just a server glitch and retrying after a short time would have worked.

You can also get this message when you're **already at max resonator limits**. e.g. as an L5 player, you have 2 L5 res deployed and try to 'upgrade' an L4 on the portal - it will say 'no usable resonators', because you cannot deploy a 3rd one.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain it as I am still Level 1 myself. _Error message fail!_

Comment: It does glitch sometimes though, I have seen the message when I should have been able to upgrade. Then I revisit the portal 5 mins later and it works :P